# DirectoryInfo.GetFiles Method (String, SearchOption) exception: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path

Tags: .net

I'm using the above method, and get the above exception.
I don't see any illegal characters in the Directory name (there're other directories which return results as expected).
When I call the static `Directory.GetFiles(String, String, SearchOption)` with the same directory that fails on the `DirectoryInfo` method, there's no problem and the method returns as expected.
Any idea what could cause this misbehavior?

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Comment: This would seem the most obvious thing in the world, but *what is the string you're passing in?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem when I was scanning a directory on a mac (through a network share).

> DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(@"//macbook/sharedfolder")

Apperenately it's quite legal on a mac to have chars like <,>,? in a filename, but on windows it's not.

When one of the filenames in the directory had invalid chars I got this "illegal characters" error.

Comment: I think this is the cause for my exception, too. I ended up using try-catch block in a foreach loop that iterates Directory.GetFiles(String, String, SearchOption) results... not very efficient.

Comment: You don't really have to skip this directory. When you iterate the file paths returned from  Directory.GetFiles, you construct each FileInfo in a try-catch, and this way you only skip the files which violate the windows' style file name.

Answer (score 1):

as stated in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx), an `ArgumentException` is raised when

> searchPattern contains one or more invalid characters defined by the
>   GetInvalidPathChars method.

(`searchPattern` is the first String argument of the method).

to test this, you may try

```
var invalidChars = <yourSearchPattern>.Select(x => x).Intersect(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()).ToList();
```

if you find something in invalidChars, you'll have found the source of your problem.

**EDIT**

Why does it work with [Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ? I must admit I don't understand.

An `ArgumentException` is raised

if the first argument(`path`) has invalid chars (or `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`), or

if the second argument (`searchPattern`)

> does not contain a valid pattern

And a valid pattern is

> The parameter cannot end in two periods ("..") or contain two periods
>   ("..") followed by DirectorySeparatorChar or
>   AltDirectorySeparatorChar, nor can it contain any of the characters in
>   InvalidPathChars.

As `InvalidPathChars` (obsolete) give me the same result as `GetInvalidPathChars()`, at least in .net 4.5, I must admit I'm stuck.

You may use a different version of .net, where there's a difference between the two ?