# How to search for a file in DataGgridView which is without database

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, search, datagridview

My search function is happening now in a listbox.. i am populating all the files from a folder to a listbox.. and i am able to search for a filename accordingly from the listbox. But my real ideaa is to search from a gridview. So i need your help to modify this and search within my gridview.. How can i do that.
Need to search on basis of my column name `Drawing_Number`

**snapshot of my gridview, I need to search for these files**

[image]

Codes for searching inside a listbox

Code Snippet:

```
  private void SrchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\St\Fabrication\Draft");
        FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles();
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            string search = textBox1.Text;
            lbxResults.Items.Clear();
            foreach (FileInfo curFile in fi)
            {
                if (curFile.Name.ToUpper().IndexOf(search.ToUpper()) != -1)
                {
                    lbxResults.Items.Add(curFile.Name);
                }
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Able to search from a listbox..

snapshot of searched files coming in listbox [image: Search]

**I need to convert this search to my gridview. How can i do this!!!**

Comment: What type is your app? Is it a web app or a desktop app?

Comment: @Christos desktop app

Comment: How you do *populating in my gridview* ? You could store all information (search result or just a file name) in invisible (or visible) column. Then access it through `Rows` enumeration by column index, cast to type (`string` if it's just file name), done.

Comment: @Sinatr i have updated my codes please se that.. i want to upgrade this listbox search to a datagrid search

Comment: Stavy, you have a strange way of changing your questions around.. So you want to search neither in a ListBox nor in a DataGridView but in a collection of filenames and put the result into a DGV or what? And the 1st image is what? The desired outcome? Where do the numbers come from? What is the user input in the TextBox?

Comment: I think varsha has already given you a suggestion. have you tried that?

Comment: @TaW i dint change the question i just added more details and more codes.. so that you can help out easily!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer..
it was a simple thing!!!

Here is the code:

```
        (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter
            = string.Format(@"`Drawing Number` LIKE '%{0}%' OR `Release Path` LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
        dataGridView1.Focus();
        textBox1.Focus();
        int rowCount = dataGridView1.BindingContext[dt].Count;
        if (rowCount == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No results");
        }
```

I found the help from this link: [Filtering DataGridView without changing datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource)

Comment: ohh.. then its great :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this method on your button click event. This will check the file is exist in the specified folder path in `folderPath` variable. `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(string path, string patern)` function will find the files from the folder if the string matched and assign the value in the Drawing cell.

```
string folderPath = @"C:\St\Fabrication\Draft";
for (int i = 0; dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string strSearch = string.Format("*{0}*", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Drawing_Number"].Value);
    string[] arrFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, strSearch);
    if (arrFiles.Length > 0)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Drawing"].Value = arrFiles[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: @StacyKebler what is the value of `strSearch` is displaying? make sure it should not be blank or null. This problem can be occurred when more than one wildcard character are placed incorrectly or one or more invalid characters defined. ie. it should be `*FILE_NAME*`. but, it should not be `**` or `**MY_FILE` where `*` is a wildcard character. take a look at this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx) article and this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17473343/3761928) too.

Comment: @Nimesh u there,, Hello n

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that checks for a match and selects all rows that match.
Notes:

Your column name does not include a space as you wrote.

I show the number of matches in a Label.

The matches can be done with a few options. Pick what you need or give the user checkboxes..

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string columnName = "filename";

        bool partial = false;  // full comparison or only a substring is searched
        bool includeExtensions = true;  // include the file extension in the search
        bool ignoreCase = true;   // make the search case-(in)sensitive

        string search = textBox1.Text;
        if (ignoreCase) search = search.ToLowerInvariant();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string v = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[columnName].Value.ToString();
            if (ignoreCase) v = v.ToLowerInvariant();

            string f = includeExtensions ? 
                        Path.GetFileName(v) : Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(v);

            if (partial) dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = (f.IndexOf(search) >= 0);
            else dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = (f == search);
        }
        label1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count.ToString() + " files found.";       
    }
```

Comment: the label1 is always showing 0 files found. even though the file is there its still showing 0 files.

Comment: did you check the options?? what's the name of the file?

Comment: @sorry.. can u come again!!! i didn't get what u mean by options.. What u have to do with that

Comment: How can you not understand 'bool' when they are in the code: `
bool partial = false;
bool includeExtensions = true;
bool ignoreCase = true` I put them there so you can better control how the search should work. It is up to you to decide how to use them. In my test programm I coupled them to checkboxes, so I can test in various ways..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61452/discussion-between-stacy-kebler-and-taw).

Comment: i have updated my codes please see that.. i want to upgrade this listbox search to a datagrid search